Creating a Dependent Ordinal variable from Independent Ordinal Variables (all with 6 levels) using Kmodes Clustering technique
I want to create a dependent ordinal variable from independent ordinal variables with 6 levels {'Very satisfied': 5, 'Satisfied': 4,'Neither satisfied nor dissatisfied': 3,'Dissatisfied': 2,'Very Dissatisfied': 1,'Not Applicable' : 0} by applying kmodes clustering to create a dependent variable ("Overall Satisfaction"), and fit an ordinal logistic regression model. is this appropriate? and how can i go about doing it?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The problem sounds more like forming a multivariate Y with all the component ordinal scales.  One way to do that is to construct a tall and thin dataset and use subjects as random effects so that the different scales are connected correlation-wise.

please clarify your answer with an example. Thank you.
